# Reusable Questions in MySQL Survey Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm working on a Reusable Survey database design. So the idea is.

> A Client has many users, A client has categories which consist of questions. Every User has to answer all questions to complete the Survey. Those answers are stored in the Answers table.

## The hard part

Some users are coaches, so a coach can fill in the survey for the user, thus providing a score on what they **would answer in the place of the user**. So we can later compare what the user answered and what the coach answered for each user. That's not to hard! The following is:

### After some months we should be able to let the users redo the surveys, so with new answers to all the still existing questions.

I'm wondering if my db design is allright for this.
I have the feeling that this isn't optimal.

[image]

For example the following queries seem difficult with my design

- For a given Scan, give me all categories and questions
  (because of the many tables in between)

Looking very forward to your responses!

Comment: you may get a better response if you posted this in db exchange http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Isn't completing a survey a bit like placing an order?  On most shopping sites, customers don't "buy products". They place orders. You then look at the details of that order t see when it was placed and what items (see answers) are contained within it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Strawberry, care to elaborate?

Comment: Well, a shopping site might have a customers table, which relates to an orders table, which in turn relates to an order details table - which holds the product ids and quantities ordered. So, no direct link between customers and products. See where I'm going? The orders table just holds the id of the customer, the id of the order, and the date the order was placed.

Comment: Hmh, you suggest I create an answer_details table? Which holds what then? I was thinking that I need to user_id, coach_id, question_id, scan_id to determine for who, by who, on what question and in what scan edition the answer is. (thank you so much for your time)

Comment: Seems like you're missing a date field on the question or an interval field of some kind between current record and previous record of a user's answers. What I also don't see is a "questionaire" table (junction object perhaps?). I'd expect that not all questions would be asked each time by each client and that questions could be added or removed from questionaires. Your design doesn't allow for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what do you mean with a junction-object? All questions need to be filled in at all times. :) it's obligated. What would a questionaire table look like? Thank you!

Comment: But the surveys will change over time, I guarantee that. Some of what @crmprogdev is talking about is in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how you are going to want to use this information. Are you going to want to compare users scores to coaches scores to their new scores? I think that is likely. Will they end up taking the survey multiple times if they don't improve enough? Are there going to be questions that do not have integer answers? How are you going to store those results? When they create a new survey are they going to want to reuse some previous questions or answers (like yes/no). How are you going to identify a unique user, names are not unique and autogenerated IDs are unique, but how will you know which John Smith belongs to which of the 12 ids you have?

- I would rename the Answer table as SurveyResponse.
- To it I would add the datetime of the surveyresponse (so people can
  answer it multiple times and you can compare the answers) and a
  Survey ID (from the new table in the next suggestion).
- I would create a Survey table that stores the questions that belong
  to a particular survey.
- I would create a new Answer table that just has possible answers and
  an ID.
- I would create a table called SurveyQuestionAnswer which stores the
  allowed answers to the question for each survey (different surveys
  might have different possible responses to the same question).

Comment: Thank you for this great answer! The Survey table seemed useless because I have the client -> categories -> question. users belong to a client, and each client has his own categories with questions. Or am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: Think about how this is going to change over time. If someone adds a question to the category after he took the first survey, do you need to have him retake the exact survey he took originally or a new one?

Comment: Oh it's the exact same. If a question is added to the first one it's allright to appear in all surveys (I don't know if this is allowed here but do you do consulting? miguel@notflip.be)